# PowerShell - "RETURN" in function returns values two times INSTEAD of just one

Tags: function, powershell, return

I was assuming that "return" in PowerShell function will return the value and exit the function, but instead of that I am getting the values for two times!!!!???

Please assist me.
I have a default value, I have logic for retreiving the real value (if exists) but instead I am getting two fules as output - but I do not want that! I need just one value.
Thank you in advance!!!

```
function GetTenantTagValue($TAG_SET_NAME) {
    Write-Host("Tag Set Name:"+$TAG_SET_NAME)
    $TAG_SET_VALUE = "N/A"
    $TENANT_TAGS = "Customer Code/HEDGE"

    $TENANT_TAGS | ForEach-Object {
        $TAG_NAME = $_.split("/")[0]
        $TAG_VALUE = $_.split("/")[1]

        if ($TAG_NAME -eq $TAG_SET_NAME) {
            # $TAG_SET_VALUE = $TAG_VALUE
            Write-Host("Tag Value:"+$TAG_VALUE)
            Write-Host("#########################")
            return $TAG_VALUE
        }
    }
    Write-Host("Tag Set Value:"+$TAG_SET_VALUE)
    return $TAG_SET_VALUE
}
```

I invoke the function with:

```
GetTenantTagValue "Customer Code"
```

Comment: `return` doesn't work from inside a `ForEach-Object` scriptblock, use a `foreach($TAG in $TENANT_TAGS){}` loop statement instead and it'll work

Comment: To expand  @MathiasR.Jessen's comment, the ```return``` inside the script block does "work", but it only returns from the instance of the script block for the current iteration of the ```foreach-object``` statement. It doesn't terminate the parent scope (i.e the function), and any remaining ```foreach-object``` iterations will still execute. See ```@( 1, 2, 3, 4 ) | foreach-object { return $_ * 2; throw }``` for example - it outputs ```@( 2, 4, 6, 8)``` and the ```throw``` never executes.

Comment: @mclayton You should add that as an answer